# How Java VisualVM shows threads that are not running/finished?

Tags: java, multithreading, jvm, visualvm, jvisualvm

[image]

For testing I've created a thread which has just sleep in it. And I know that GC doesnt collect them for a while even if their usage is done but when you dont keep them as an object after they complete their task they should've be gone.

So for testing purposes I used Java VisualVM but this is the first time I'm using it. And I see all these timer threads lying around with 0ms but I can still see them. Is this normal? And what does this mean? If I spam thousands of them, will it slow down my app?

Comment: If the thread disappears from the list as soon as it ends, you won't have time to analyze the result, now would you? So when the app is monitored, the threads live on, for your debugging pleasure.

Comment: So those white colored boxes of threads will not appear when I run the app?

Comment: Try stopping and restarting VisualVM

Comment: @Andreas Basically what I'm asking is will this code "new Thread(task).start()" cause any problems for me? Because it'll be done massively

Comment: @Andreas it did as you said, if you post your comments as an answer I'll accept them

Comment: These are two different questions. As Andreas said, these threads are not active anymore, so likely not consuming any resources (whether they do is not recognizable in that view). But that doesn’t mean that `new Thread(task).start()` is a recommended coding style. If you do this “massively” you are wasting resources. You should use a thread pool with a maximum thread limit, to allow reusing the threads. Try [`Executors.newFixedThreadPool(number)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool(int)) or `newCachedThreadPool()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once VisualVM connects to the running JVM, *it* will keep references to all started threads, so those `Thread` objects are not garbage collected when the threads stop running.

They are retained by VisualVM so you can still see the statistics collected for them.

The `Thread` objects will become unreachable and GC'able once you exit VisualVM, so stopping and restarting VisualVM will "clear" the list of ended threads.

Comment: I can assure you that VisualVM does _not_ keep references to all started threads.

Comment: Is there any tool that can be used to find the root object that retains the threads?

Answer (score 0):

You see all that `Thread-` threads, because by default VisualVM will show you all the threads (including those, which were finished during monitoring session). To see just `Live` threads, switch `View` combo from `All threads` to `Live threads`. VisualVM does *not* keep references to all started threads, they can be garbage-collected just fine.